# openquery: datum formatting

Tags: sql, oracle, openquery

I'm trying to retrieve data from Oracle by SQL server so I'm using openquery and I'm able to get date interval this way:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM OPENQUERY(DATABASE, 
     'SELECT * FROM ORACLE.TABLE
      WHERE CREATEDATE between {d ''2013-03-23''} and {d ''2013-03-27''} ')
```

how can I do the similar query, but date interval will be in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format and stay with `openquery`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the conversion from date to string in the `openquery` statement:

```
select to_char(<datecol>, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss') . . .
```

Alternatively, you culd use `convert()` in SQL Server and do it in the outer `select`.

Comment: Your solution works, thanks, but i dont't know why, the solution I've looking for (and found today): `CREATEDATE between {ts ''2013-03-23 00:00:00''} and {ts ''2013-03-27 23:59:59''}` seems to be much faster...